# SAP WEBI sharing link for webi document as a User

Tags: webi

As a User when Open a webi document how can I share the link of the document ?

In the browser header i only see the login URL so I cannot copy it from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to right-click on your report and choose Copy Opendoc Link (or perhaps OpenDocument Link).

[image]

Whomever you share that link with will need to have permission to the report location.

What version of BusinessObjects are you using? I am on 4.3 SP02. If you are on a version lower than 4.3 the same functionality exists, but it will look different.

Noel

Comment: Cool I've also copied this at the and of the link so now if the document is shceduled the link will open the last webi document.

&fromFioriLP=true&sInstance=Last&sRefresh=N

Comment: You could set up your schedule to send an email when it completes add the "Viewer" placeholder to the Message section which results in %SI_VIEWER_URL% getting inserted into the email message. That will then always be the link to that specific instance rather than just the latest instance.